# Delete the entire row, If I found NA's in a particular column within the existing data dataset

Tags: r, na, missing-data

Kindly suggest a code for the below method.

If **Hba** column has NA then delete the entire row of that ID's.
That deletion should be done within the same dataset, not by creating the new dataset.

for Eg; here the data with table name (Hba1c_data)

```
ID  G Hba var1 var2
123 M 7.1 45   78
654 F 8.1 78   32
159 F NA  57   52
147 M NA  NA   NA
```

Expected Output (should be in the same table(Hba1c_data))

```
ID  G Hba var1 var2
123 M 7.1 45   78
654 F 8.1 78   32
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this should do the trick:

```
Hba1c_data <- Hba1c_data[!is.na(Hba1c_data$Hba),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!is.na(Hba))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     ID G       Hba  var1  var2
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   123 M       7.1    45    78
2   654 F       8.1    78    32
```